# Unable to set TEST_BROWSER_DRIVER env variable Windows 10 Meteor

Tags: javascript, testing, meteor, mocha.js

I have not been able to test my meteor app at all, previously at v1.4, I managed to launch the tests, after upgrading to 1.6, I have not been able to run the tests despite my efforts. I hope anyone can help.

Operating System: Windows 10.

Current Meteor Version: 1.6

In my environment variables, I have set path to point to my chromedriver, but still no success at all.

```
 C:\Users\Username\Documents\Dev\Proj\infilerp>TEST_BROWSER_DRIVER=chrome meteor test --once --driver-package meteortesting:mocha
'TEST_BROWSER_DRIVER' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.  



C:\Users\Username\Documents\Dev\Proj\infilerp>meteor test --full-app --

driver-package meteortesting:mocha --port 8080
[[[[[ Tests ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> A patch (Meteor 1.6.1.3) for your current release is available!
   Update this project now with 'meteor update --patch'.
=> Started MongoDB.
I20180730-17:58:52.807(8)? superadmin created
I20180730-17:58:53.166(8)?
I20180730-17:58:53.167(8)? --------------------------------
I20180730-17:58:53.167(8)? --- RUNNING APP SERVER TESTS ---
I20180730-17:58:53.168(8)? --------------------------------
I20180730-17:58:53.168(8)?
I20180730-17:58:53.168(8)?
I20180730-17:58:53.169(8)?
I20180730-17:58:53.169(8)?   0 passing (1ms)
I20180730-17:58:53.170(8)?
I20180730-17:58:53.171(8)?
I20180730-17:58:53.171(8)? --------------------------------
I20180730-17:58:53.172(8)? --- RUNNING APP CLIENT TESTS ---
I20180730-17:58:53.172(8)? --------------------------------
W20180730-17:58:53.281(8)? (STDERR) C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.6.1\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:280
W20180730-17:58:53.282(8)? (STDERR)                                             throw(ex);
W20180730-17:58:53.283(8)? (STDERR)                                             ^
W20180730-17:58:53.283(8)? (STDERR)
W20180730-17:58:53.283(8)? (STDERR) Error: Unknown driver "C:\Users\Username\Documents\Dev\Proj\infilerp\node_modules\chromedriver\lib\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe". browser-tests package requires that you set the TEST_BROWSER_DRIVER environment variable to one of the following: chrome, nightmare, phantomjs, puppeteer
W20180730-17:58:53.284(8)? (STDERR)     at startBrowser (packages/meteortesting:browser-tests/server.js:39:13)
W20180730-17:58:53.284(8)? (STDERR)     at clientTests (packages/meteortesting:mocha/server.js:138:3)
W20180730-17:58:53.284(8)? (STDERR)     at serverTests (packages/meteortesting:mocha/server.js:168:7)
W20180730-17:58:53.285(8)? (STDERR)     at mochaInstance.run.failureCount (packages/meteortesting:mocha/server.js:118:13)
W20180730-17:58:53.285(8)? (STDERR)     at done 

...    
=> Exited with code: 1
```

Comment: Did it run on Windows before or did it run on a unixoid is before?

Comment: I ran it on mac before, then I switched to windows.

Comment: Then you need to set your environment variable different. See https://superuser.com/questions/212150/how-to-set-env-variable-in-windows-cmd-line#212153

Comment: @Jankapunkt I set the env variable, but still got no where, I'm not sure if I'm doing it wrong: 
`C:\Users\Username\Documents\Dev\Proj\infilerp>SET TEST_BROWSER_DRIVER="c:\WINDOWS\chromedriver.C:\Users\Username\Documents\Dev\Proj\infilerp>TEST_BROWSER_DRIVER
'TEST_BROWSER_DRIVER' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Answer (score 2):

When working with NodeJS / Meteor on Windows, I find it much easier to run everything using npm scripts with cross-env, or with batch scripts

For the test example I would set up a script in `package.json` like this:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run",
    "test": "cross-env TEST_BROWSER_DRIVER=chrome meteor test --full-app --driver-package meteortesting:mocha --port 8080"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    ...etc
  }
}
```

`cross-env` does the job of setting the environment variable correctly across different OSs so you can run the script anywhere with `npm run test`

Or, as a batch script (Windows only):

```
set TEST_BROWSER_DRIVER=chrome
REM Optionally set other env vars you want
set TEST_WATCH=1
meteor test --full-app --driver-package meteortesting:mocha --port 8080
```

---

Also, now that `meteortesting:mocha` supports `puppeteer` I strongly recommend using that as a browser driver. I've had way less headaches using it:

```
npm install --save-dev puppeteer
```

and

```
TEST_BROWSER_DRIVER=puppeteer
```

You may need to update `meteortesting:browser-tests` to version 1.0.0 to enable pupeteer support.

Comment: Thank you! I managed to move past the `TEST_BROWSER_DRIVER` issue. But now I have another one: 

I added `"test": "cross-env TEST_BROWSER_DRIVER=chrome meteor test --full-app --driver-package meteortesting:mocha --port 8080"`

and ran `npm run test`

but I have another problem:

`TypeError: options.toCapabilities is not a function
    at startChrome (packages/meteortesting:browser-tests/browser/chromedriver.js:46:82)
    at startBrowser (packages/meteortesting:browser-tests/server.js:23:7)
    at clientTests (packages/meteortesting:mocha/server.js:138:3)`

Comment: looks like a bug in `meteortesting:browser-tests` for chromedriver. Does switching to puppeteer fix that?

Comment: I'm currently using: `meteor node -v v8.9.4`. After I changed `selenium` to `selenium-webdriver@3.0.0-beta-2`. The error went away, but I still couldn't get the page to load with all the tests on `localhost:8080`. The app crashed with `code 0`.

I am wondering if I can change meteor node to use `v6.1.3` but I haven't found a way to do that. `puppeteer` also crashed with `code 0` even after downgrading `selenium`

Comment: I changed my port to 3100 and I seemed to have gotten a step further. Also, instead of using `meteor npm run 'chrome-test'`, I simply run `meteor test --driver-package meteortesting:mocha --port 3100` and my console is outputting the test results. BUT when I go to `localhost:3100`, I'm getting this in the console: `modules.js?hash=b0c78242e1bea8373c5f38529a072c3214bf0c64:32074 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at patch (modules.js?hash=b0c78242e1bea8373c5f38529a072c3214bf0c64:32074)
    at graceful-fs.js (modules.js?`

Comment: could you share the version of `meteor, node, chromedriver` and `selenium` you are running? Also when you run your command, do you run `meteor npm run test` ? which will lead to running `TEST_BROWSER_DRIVER=chrome meteor test --full-app --driver-package meteortesting:mocha --port 3100`  ??

Comment: Currently running `Meteor 1.7.0.3` (which uses `node 8.11.3`), and using `puppeteer@1.5.0` so no chromedriver or selenium. `meteortesting:mocha@1.0.0`, `meteortesting:browser-tests@1.0.0`. Launching tests with `cross-env TEST_BROWSER_DRIVER=puppeteer meteor test --once --driver-package meteortesting:mocha --raw-logs --settings settings.json`

Comment: How can you set browser options (chrome location etc) with `meteor test --driver-package meteortesting:mocha` ? with npm i could load a config file

Comment: @Gobliins it depends which `TEST_BROWSER_DRIVER` you use, they will have their own configs. puppeteer for instance bundles a chromium binary for it's own use, rather than needing configuration. Selenium and phantomjs have their own config patterns. If you need more help, please open a new question. I recommend the Meteor forums for more open ended questions and fewer rules for what you're allowed to ask and how